# Select all data except top 1 from a duplicated database

Tags: sql-server

I have this query which returns duplicate TIID numbers from my database:

```
SELECT 
    TIID, CIID
FROM 
    INST_TASKS
WHERE 
    CIID IN (SELECT CIID
             FROM INST_TASKS
             GROUP BY CIID
             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

The above code returns this result:

```
TIID    CIID
-------------
187831  80162
187836  80162
187838  80162
194628  80522
194629  80522
194630  80812
194631  80812
194632  80522
194633  81444
194634  81444
194635  80812
194636  81594
194637  81594
194638  81444
194639  81594
194640  81626
194641  81626
194642  81700
194643  81626
194644  81700
194645  81700
```

What I want to do is to select `TIID` numbers except top 1 for each `CIID` number.

The desired result should be as :

```
TIID    CIID
-------------
187836  80162
187838  80162
194629  80522
194632  80522
194631  80812
194635  80812
194634  81444
194638  81444
194637  81594
194639  81594
194641  81626
194643  81626
194644  81700
194645  81700
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Row_Number and filter by > 1 as below:

```
Select * from (
   Select *, RowN = Row_Number() over(Partition by CIID Order by TIID)  from #yourtable ) a
where a.RowN > 1
```

Output as below:

```
+--------+-------+
|  TIID  | CIID  |
+--------+-------+
| 187838 | 80162 |
| 187836 | 80162 |
| 194632 | 80522 |
| 194629 | 80522 |
| 194635 | 80812 |
| 194631 | 80812 |
| 194638 | 81444 |
| 194634 | 81444 |
| 194639 | 81594 |
| 194637 | 81594 |
| 194643 | 81626 |
| 194641 | 81626 |
| 194645 | 81700 |
| 194644 | 81700 |
+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query --

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT TIID
        ,CIID
        ,Row_Number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY CIID ORDER BY TIID
            ) AS RowNum
    FROM INST_TASKS
    )
SELECT TIID
    ,CIID
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNum > 1;
```